# How to concatenate a variable list of files in puppet

Tags: puppet, concatenation, hiera

I have configured a list of template name using hiera. Within puppet, I want to concatenate all these files together into a single file.

Also the template function accepts multiple arguments, it doesn't support using an array variable as an argument.

Does anyone have any clever ways of doing this?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're trying to do? I kinda get what you're asking: an array variable of template paths, then being able to do something like `template($array_of_templates)`?

Comment: @Peter, I have a configuration file that I am installing on different servers. I would like to compose this file from a "base" configuration file that all the servers get and then be able to add additional configuration based on my hiera config. I could then just use hiera_array to build the array dynamically, and then pass that to the template function.  I saw there was a feature request for this, but its 4 years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the [puppetlabs-stdlib](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib) library installed?

Since you can pass template a [comma separated list](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/function.html#template), you could use the `stdlib` function [join()](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib#join) to convert the array into a string.

```
$my_array = hiera('array_to_lookup')
...
content => template(join($my_array, ','))
```

Does that work for your requirements?